# How to configure splash screen after plymouth

Tags: boot, xorg, gdm, plymouth

I have configured my splash screen for plymouth - and it works perfectly. I've also configured the display manager (I'm using gdm). In between these two I get a very brief splash screen - a kind of swirl of multi-coloured ubuntu like colours. Where does this splash screen get set, and how do I change it?

Edit:
Here is a video of my boot sequence, showing the screen in question:
http://youtube.com/watch?v=fMM6I-c7ga8

Comment: It might be useful to upload a picture of this screen/video of your boot sequence; I can't think of anything (off the top of my head) that matches your description

Comment: Is it possible to take a screenshot at this point in the boot sequence??

Comment: I meant with a camera :)

Comment: Ha! LOL. Here is a video of my boot sequence: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fMM6I-c7ga8

Comment: @MattCaswell The only way of screenshotting grub is with a Virtual Machine: https://askubuntu.com/a/1102423/307523

Answer (score 1):

I'm going out on a limb here.

If the problem that you're having with Plymouth has anything to do with proprietary ATI / Nvidia graphics drivers, try [this script](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/script-to-fix-ubuntu-plymouth-for.html).

Also there are two Plymouth Managers that my help you

A GUI called [Splashscreen](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Splash+Screen+Manager?content=134231) Manager, and the other GUI is called [Plymouth Manager](https://launchpad.net/plymouth-manager/+download)

Note:Plymouth does not reliably work with nVidia drivers and during bootup a blank screen may result for several seconds.

Comment: Thanks Mitch. However I don't think the splash screen is actually coming from plymouth itself. Plymouth is working fine (although I have historically had problems with nVidia drivers, this is no longer a problem for me). The screen is shown immediately after plymouth finishes, but before gdm starts. Take a look at the video I've added to the question to see what I mean.

Comment: Upvoting to prevent this old question from being bumped to home page :)