# How to replace the background image in the default plymouth theme

Tags: plymouth

Is it possible to replace the pink purple colour of Ubuntu's default plymouth theme with an image?

Comment: Take a look at my answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/300848/how-to-configure-splash-screen-after-plymouth/305589#305589), see if it helps.

Comment: but that doesnt answer my question... both packages require admin privileges

Comment: Did you try with `sudo`?

Answer (score 0):

It is!

If you Google search "Plymouth Themes" you will find an assortment of themes you can install and modify to your liking.

If your serious about it, you could also look into Plymouth scripting and building your own themes.